# Logic Pro 9: importing and editing drum recordings from a Pro Tools session

Tags: logic-pro

I'm editing drums from a session recorded in Pro Tools, consisting of 10 close-mic tracks and 7 overhead / room tracks. The latter are in split-stereo format, and when importing them, Logic automatically packs the left and right files together in the media bin. Which is fine with me, but comp-editing these tracks is impossible. The official solution a-la Apple seems  to be going over to the media bin, splitting these files one-by-one back into separate left and right tracks, deleting the stereo tracks from the arrange window and adding the mono ones instead. However, with 3-4 takes per song and 3 distinct stereo pairs, this is a small nightmare.

Does anyone know of a way to either enable comp-editing on stereo tracks (unlikely) or stopping Logic from joining these tracks to begin with?

I also did a bit of research and one solution seems to be to disable Universal Track Mode; however, doing that causes Logic to not play back any sound in my sessions, presumably because they already make use of UTM.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For whom it may concern - this is what I eventually did:
Pro Tools exports split-stereo files as pairs of files with an identical name and a .L.wav and .R.wav suffix accordingly. When logic detects such a pair during import, it automatically combines it into an interleaved region.

What I ended up doing was renaming all files with the aforementioned name pattern, using OS X's Automator, to a .Left.wav and .Right.wav pattern (before importing them), fooling Logic and preventing it from combining it in the first place.